# How to update location in ionic from background?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

So in my app i need to send my location's coordinates every 5 minutes through web service, I need to send it when app is in background state also. I am using background-geolocation plugin. Anyone please help me to do that. Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks .I just added the plugin. only i done this.

Comment: If you check the plugin's documentation, you will find the code to use the plugin. If you still face issues after trying it's code, you should post the code in a question and the errors you face.

Comment: how to create ipa file in cordova?

Answer (score 0):

The other way running prcocess in background is by using android core if you know that.

I was also facing the problem of running process in background. I have installed the background plugin too. But it did not work. Then i wrote a customized code in android.

Steps i followed. 
1.) Stored the data in cordova prefrences.
2.) Fetch the data from prefrences in android core file( a java file).
3.) Written service in android that check the prefrences after every 2 minutes.

I know this is quiet tuff but this was the only solution i got in hybrid app.